# ¿Como puedo insertar datos desde SQLite a mi DataGridView? WindowsForms

Tags: c#, windows-forms, sqlite, interfaz-gráfica

[image: Form1]
[image: Form2]Tengo el siguiente código que se ejecuta cada vez que se hace click en el botón AGREGAR ITEM y que crea una nueva fila con los datos ingresados en los textBox de más arriba en el DataGridView de más abajo.

```
    // AGREGA UN PRODUCTO
    private void btnAgregarItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Pagos.Rows.Add(txtID.Text, txtNombre.Text, txtPrecio.Text, txtCantidad.Text, etiquetaSubTotalNum.Text);

            string mesa = this.numMesa;
            int id_producto = Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text.ToString());
            string nombre = txtNombre.Text.ToString();
            double precio = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrecio.Text.ToString());
            double cantidad = Convert.ToDouble(txtCantidad.Text.ToString());
            double subtotal = Convert.ToDouble(etiquetaSubTotalNum.Text.ToString());

            String consulta = "INSERT INTO Productos (mesa, id_producto, nombre, precio, cantidad, subtotal) VALUES (@mesa, @id_producto, @nombre, @precio, @cantidad, @subtotal)";
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(consulta, conexion);

            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@mesa", mesa));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@id_producto", id_producto));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@nombre", nombre));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@precio", precio));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@cantidad", cantidad));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@subtotal", subtotal));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
```

La función cargar() necesito que se ejecute cuando se abra una mesa, osea que cada vez que se haga click en el botón de una mesa me traiga los datos de esa mesa desde mi tabla Productos en mi base de datos y me inserte esos datos de la tabla dentro de las columnas de mi dataGridView:

```
  public void cargar()
    {
        string mesa = this.numMesa;
        string consulta = "select * from Productos where mesa = @mesa";
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(consulta, conexion);
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@mesa", mesa));
        using (SQLiteDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (read.Read())
            {
                Pagos.Rows.Add(new object[] {
    read.GetValue(0),
    //read.GetValue(read.GetOrdinal("mesa")),
    read.GetValue(read.GetOrdinal("id_producto")),
    read.GetValue(read.GetOrdinal("nombre")),
    read.GetValue(read.GetOrdinal("precio")),
    read.GetValue(read.GetOrdinal("cantidad")),
    read.GetValue(read.GetOrdinal("subtotal"))
    });
            }
        }

    }
```

Mi tabla productos está compuesta por las siguientes columnas:

```
mesa, id_producto, nombre, precio, cantidad, subtotal
```

Mi `dataGridView` tiene las columnas:

```
id_productos, nombre, precio, cantidad, subtotal.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITADO**

**Opción 1**

Una forma de leer fila a fila seria como en este ejemplo:

```
public void cargar()
{
    string mesa = this.numMesa;
    string consulta = "select * from Productos where mesa = @mesa";
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(consulta, conexion);
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@mesa", mesa));
    using (SQLiteDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
      while (read.Read())
      {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 
        read.GetValue(0),  
        read.GetValue(read.GetOrdinal("mesa")),  
        read.GetValue(read.GetOrdinal("id_producto")),
        read.GetValue(read.GetOrdinal("nombre")),
        read.GetValue(read.GetOrdinal("precio")),
        read.GetValue(read.GetOrdinal("cantidad")),
        read.GetValue(read.GetOrdinal("subtotal"))  
        });
      }
   }

}
```

Si quieres poner alguna condición podrías controlarla en el constructor.

**Opción 2**

Por otra parte lo mas logico es añadir al `DataSource` del `datagridview` todo el contenido de la tabla:

```
public void cargar()
{
    string mesa = this.numMesa;
    string consulta = "select * from Productos where mesa = @mesa";
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(consulta, conexion);
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@mesa", mesa));
    var sqlda = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
    using (dt = new DataTable())
    {
        sqlda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola @Gerardo, y gracias por tu respuesta. Te consulto de nuevo porque estoy probando el código pero me tira un SQLite Exception en la línea using (SQLiteDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader()) del primer ejemplo. Dice que no le estoy pasando suficientes parametros al ExecuteReader() y no sé que parametros le tengo que pasar. Por otro lado, los columnName que pones entre parentesis debería cambiarlos por los nombres de mis columnas verdad ?

Comment: Hola @NachoZveDeLaTorre, edito la respuesta no había añadido el parámetro `mesa` y he cambiado los nombres de las columnas por los que has puesto. Si tienes algún problema más comentamelo

Comment: Hola @Gerardo y gracias de nuevo por tu ayuda! Te comento, viendo tu código, que ayer me rompía (es decir, dejaba de funcionar) en la línea donde te marcaba antes del primer ejemplo!
Parece que al ExecuteReader() le tngo que pasar algún parámetro pero no sé que pasarle. Por lo que veo en tu edición el código sigue siendo el mismo salvo por los nombres de las columnas. No creo que me ande cuando lo pruebe más tarde !! Alguna idea ??

Comment: Por lo que veo en la documentación no tiene parámetros obligatoriamente. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitecommand.executereader?view=msdata-sqlite-2.0.0

Comment: En todo momento se da por hecho que la cadena de conexión es la correcta y que has realizado el `conexion.Open()` antes de ejecutar este código. Otra cosa que se me puede ocurrir es quitar el `SQLiteParameter`y usar un valor directamente en la declaración de la query por ver si falla en ese punto, pero dudo mucho que el fallo pueda estar ahí.  Un saludo

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda Gerardo. Ya lo he resulto ! Te mando un abrazo